# A space at the beginning of a row that tries to take up maxWidth or less

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

This seems like it should be simple, but I'm having a lot of difficulty. I want to lay out a series of widgets that we'll call [`indent`, `icon`, `text`]. `indent` should try to be 160 wide, but gives up space if that would push the other widgets out of bounds. `icon` has a fixed width. `text` takes up at least 50 and accepts more if indent is at its maximum.

Can this be done with a Row? FlexItems? ConstrainedBoxes?

(I wish I just had a Cassowary general constraint solver x] apparently they had that in flutter for a bit, but took it out.)

Comment: You can do quite a bit with properly placed https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ConstrainedBox-class.html widgets.

Comment: I know about ConstrainedBox. A solution would *involve* setting minWidth and maxWidth values, but that doesn't seem to get you there. Please show me how you would do this, because I'm seriously increasingly confident that it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, no, extraordinarily, I think even the very simple thing I describe in the title is impossible under the Flex layout algorithm? There's one thing I didn't try (flex:99999 with maxWidth:160 on the first element, flex:1 on the second), but I don't think it would work either. The behaviour I describe in the description seems *definitely* impossible with flex. So I'll give up on the standard layout widgets. I've ended up taking a sort of more manual approach by hand-specifying the layout rules I wanted in a `LayoutBuilder` widget. This does the job.

```
LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) {
      double totalWidth = constraints.maxWidth;
      double indentWidth = 160;
      double childMinWidth = 50;
      double actualIndentWidth =
          (totalWidth < indentWidth + childMinWidth)
              ? indentWidth = max(totalWidth - childMinWidth, 0)
              : indentWidth = indentWidth;
      double childWidth = totalWidth - actualIndentWidth;
      return Row(children: [
        SizedBox(width: actualIndentWidth),
        SizedBox(width: totalWidth - actualIndentWidth, child: child)
      ])
    )
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok. So, if I were to need something like this, I would use the different properties of the `Row` Widget and `Spacer`.

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
  children: <Widget>[
    Spacer(flex: 3),
    icon,
    Spacer(flex: 1),
    text,
  ],
)
```

According to me, this should work.

Comment: I don't really know how I can clarify the description of what I need more than I have already. No, this does not behave as described.